# Setting the interval of x-axis for seaborn plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a set of subplots to plot. Here, how do we set the interval for x-axis in the subplot in second row, i.e `ax4` to `ax6`. Currently all the values from 1 to 100 are printed as shown in the figure. I tried `ax4.set_xticks(range(1,100,5))`. But there, the range shown was 1 to 20. I was expecting a range from 1 to 100, with an interval of 5, i.e. `1,5,10...95,100`

Currently the plot has x-axis as shown below. I have not added the code for first row.

[image]

```
yInit = initRes
yInit = yInit[(yInit['nodeSKT'] < 92) & (yInit['nodeSKT'] > 1)]

sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=2, rc={"lines.linewidth": 1.2})
fig, (ax4, ax5, ax6) = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=3,figsize=(18,10))
plt.figure()

xval = 'nodeSKT'
sns.pointplot(x=xval, y='lemmaPrec', data=yInit,join=False,ax=ax4)
sns.pointplot(x=xval, y='wordPrec',color="#2ecc71",data=yInit, join=False,ax=ax4)
sns.pointplot(x=xval, y='lemmaReca', data=yInit,join=False,ax=ax5)
sns.pointplot(x=xval, y='wordReca',color="#2ecc71",data=yInit, join=False,ax=ax5)
sns.pointplot(x=xval, y='lemmaFsco', data=yInit,join=True,ax=ax6)
sns.pointplot(x=xval, y='wordFsco',color="#2ecc71",data=yInit, join=False,ax=ax6)
plt.savefig('lem_fscore.png')
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Seaborn `pointplot` is a categorical plot. This means that the different categories are simply placed one by one along the x axis.

The idea would therefore be to change the locator as well as the formatter for the xticks.

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.randint(0,20,size=(100))
y = np.random.rand(100)

ax = sns.pointplot(x,y )
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())

plt.show()
```

[image]