# Spacing of x-axis label in Seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to plot a moving average plot, data is all fine.

The problem I have is with the x-axis labels, the labels are all overlapping although I have already rotated it to 90 deg.

Increasing the width of the image upon a certain point only increases the leftmost and rightmost column instead of evenly distributing the width of all of the columns.

The labels are not numerical, it is a string consisting of both numbers and characters, for example : 0424NA581G

Is it possible to

1. plot the x-axis labels by certain intervals? Data points all need to remain but I can afford to let go of the axis labels

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639096/setting-the-interval-of-x-axis-for-seaborn-plot) but it turns my labels into 0,5,10,15 etc. and not my original labels

2. To evenly distribute the column width so that by simply increasing the image size I can resolve this issue.

Thank you !

```
sns.set_context('talk')

plt.figure(figsize=(50,10))

# Time-series plot
sns.lineplot(x='batch_no',
            y='hardness',
            label='Daily',
            data=df_NA,
            ci=None)

# Rolling average plot
sns.lineplot(x='batch_no',
            y='7_batch_average',
            label='7-batch average',
            data=df_NA,
            ci=None)

plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("NA hardness")

plt.xticks(rotation="90")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plt.xticks()` for setting that

```
sns.set_context('talk')
plt.figure(figsize=(50,10))

# Time-series plot
sns.lineplot(x='batch_no', y='hardness', label='Daily', data=data, ci=None)

# Rolling average plot
sns.lineplot(x='batch_no', y='7_batch_average', label='7-batch average', data=data, ci=None)

plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("NA hardness")
plt.xticks(rotation="90")

plt.xticks(data['batch_no'][::50])    # set here, ticks at step of 50

plt.show()
```

Ticks at step 50
[image]

Ticks at step 10
[image]

Comment: instead of `plt.xticks(rotation="90")` use `plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")`